# How to highlight all cells between drag start and drag end in current row, Drag can be only possible the current selection row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to highlight  all the cells between drag start and drag end in current row, Drag can be only possible the current selection row, need to prevent vertical dragging

check my fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/kannankds/3xakkja9/3/

```
$(function () {
    var isMouseDown = false;
    $("#mytable td")
        .mousedown(function () {
            isMouseDown = true;
            $(this).toggleClass("hilight");
            var $this = $(this);
            parent = $this.closest('tr').get(0);
            return false; // prevent text selection
        })
        .mouseover(function () {
            if (isMouseDown) {
                $(this).toggleClass("hilight");
            }
        });
    $(document)
        .mouseup(function () {
            isMouseDown = false;
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/3xakkja9/7/

add some modifications in Rio's code

```
$(function () {
    var isMouseDown = false;
    var currentTr;

    $("#mytable td")
        .mousedown(function () {
        isMouseDown = true;

        var $this = $(this);
        currentTr = $this.parent();  //## new

        clear(currentTr)  //## clear all td hilight befor drag start

        $this.addClass("hilight");


        return false; // prevent text selection
    })
        .mouseover(function () {
        if (currentTr.get(0) != $(this).parent().get(0)) {  //## new
            return false;
        }

        if (isMouseDown) {
            $(this).addClass("hilight");
        }
    });

    $(document)
        .mouseup(function () {
        isMouseDown = false;
    });
});

function clear($tr) {
    $tr.find('td').removeClass('hilight')
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this out. The idea is just remember the row where mousedown starts, and see if it's same as current row in mouseover.

```
$(function () {
  var isMouseDown = false;
  var currentTr;    
  $("#mytable td")
    .mousedown(function () {
      isMouseDown = true;

      $(this).toggleClass("hilight");
         var $this = $(this);
         currentTr = $this.closest('tr').get(0);
      return false; // prevent text selection
    })
    .mouseover(function () {
        if( currentTr != $(this).closest('tr').get(0)){
            return false;
        }

      if (isMouseDown) {
        $(this).toggleClass("hilight");
      }
           });

  $(document)
    .mouseup(function () {
      isMouseDown = false;
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3xakkja9/5/

Comment: ya its right but one more thing need to colour all cells between drag start and drag ends

Comment: when we are clicking on first cell and dragging outside to last cell then need to colour all cells beteen starting and ending cell